# Magento 2.2.4 Product sorting list by price on category page - How to fix Low to High Sorting Issue

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, catalog-price-rules, luma-theme, product-prices

Magento 2.2.4
It is expected that catalog category page show products sorted by price correctly, taking account that special price of the configurable product should not make difference to price indexer process

Indexer process is using configurable product special price to update catalog_product_index_price letting the category page sorting products in the wrong way.

**How to fix Low to High Sorting Issue**

[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this one? I'm having the same issue in magento 2.3